# OpenEmbedded (Yocto) recipe for Python validators library

Tags: python, setuptools, openembedded

I want to include the Python library *[validators](https://pypi.org/project/validators/)* in my OpenEmbedded build. I am working with the Kirkstone release and the latest version of *validators* is 0.22.0. There is no recpipe, so I added it myself:

```
inherit pypi

SUMMARY = "Python Data Validation for Humans™"
HOMEPAGE = "https://python-validators.github.io/validators"
LICENSE = "MIT"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=fcf28bd09a60e145c3171c531b9e677d"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "77b2689b172eeeb600d9605ab86194641670cdb73b60afd577142a9397873370"

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

The build runs through, but the package is not correctly installed. In `/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages` I get the folder `UNKNOWN-0.0.0.dist-info`, which contains some meta information including the correct license file, but no Python files.

I played around inheriting various Python build system classes, but no success. I noticed that  *validatoirs*' `pyproject.toml` file mentions *setuptools* version 61:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61"]
```

While `meta-oe-core` only contains version 59.5.0 (`python3-setuptools_59.5.0.bb`).

Answer (score 1):

Your recipe with a slight reordering for style and the inherit of `python_setuptools_build_meta` works fine:

```
SUMMARY = "Python Data Validation for Humans™"
HOMEPAGE = "https://python-validators.github.io/validators"
LICENSE = "MIT"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=fcf28bd09a60e145c3171c531b9e677d"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "77b2689b172eeeb600d9605ab86194641670cdb73b60afd577142a9397873370"

inherit pypi python_setuptools_build_meta

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

```
$ oe-pkgdata-util list-pkg-files -p python3-validators

python3-validators:
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators-0.22.0.dist-info/LICENSE
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators-0.22.0.dist-info/METADATA
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators-0.22.0.dist-info/RECORD
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators-0.22.0.dist-info/WHEEL
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators-0.22.0.dist-info/top_level.txt
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/__init__.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/__pycache__/_extremes.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/__pycache__/between.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/__pycache__/btc_address.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/__pycache__/card.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/__pycache__/country_code.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/__pycache__/domain.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/__pycache__/email.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/__pycache__/hashes.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/__pycache__/hostname.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/__pycache__/iban.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/__pycache__/ip_address.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/__pycache__/length.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/__pycache__/mac_address.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/__pycache__/slug.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/__pycache__/url.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/__pycache__/utils.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/__pycache__/uuid.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/_extremes.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/between.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/btc_address.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/card.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/country_code.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/domain.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/email.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/hashes.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/hostname.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/i18n/__init__.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/i18n/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/i18n/__pycache__/es.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/i18n/__pycache__/fi.cpython-311.pyc
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/i18n/es.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/i18n/fi.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/iban.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/ip_address.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/length.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/mac_address.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/slug.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/url.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/utils.py
    /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/validators/uuid.py
```

Comment: FYI https://lore.kernel.org/openembedded-devel/20231130113054.2687686-1-ross.burton@arm.com/T/#u

Comment: For me the output of this command is different:
    python3-validators:
            /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/UNKNOWN-0.0.0.dist-info/LICENSE
            /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/UNKNOWN-0.0.0.dist-info/METADATA
            /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/UNKNOWN-0.0.0.dist-info/RECORD
            /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/UNKNOWN-0.0.0.dist-info/WHEEL
            /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/UNKNOWN-0.0.0.dist-info/top_level.txt
    python3-validators-dbg:
    python3-validators-dev:

Comment: Maybe it needs that upgraded setuptools?

Comment: Did you build with a newer version of setuptools? Are you on a newer Yocto release than Kirkstone?

Comment: I'm using the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t actually inherit a class to build the code. Try `setuptools_build_meta`.

Comment: I tried that as well, but it didn't change the outcome.